# Unable to access controls inside JuiceUI dialog

Tags: juice-ui

When I do a postback, the values of asp.net controls that I have placed inside of a Juice UI dialog are empty.

Below is the client-side dialog code.  Neither the textbox nor the dropdownlist retain their values.  So when I type something in the textbox and try to access it on the server side with mTxtAddNote.Text, it is empty.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just a limitation with using JuiceUI dialogs that I will have to work around?

```
<div id="dlgAddNote" title="LOA Application" runat="server">
    <div class="pagetitle" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
        Add Note:
    </div>
    <div>
        <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 1%; white-space: nowrap; padding-right: 15px; vertical-align: top;" class="boldtext">
                    Type:
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="mDdlNoteType" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 1%; white-space: nowrap; padding-right: 15px; vertical-align: top;" class="boldtext">
                    Note:
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="mTxtAddNote" Columns="50" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll look into this and see if there's an issue with Juice UI specifically, or if there's an edge case that the library needs to work around.

As an aside unrelated to Juice UI, I'd like to suggest that your use of tables in this case is incorrect. Tables should be used to display only tabular data, or in the rare instance where they're the only layout option available. Inline css (set on the style attribute) is also discouraged. I'd recommend using css classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed that this is a bug and have created an issue for it. You can track the progress of it here https://github.com/appendto/juiceui/issues/24

**Edit**

Just pushed a fix for this. The fix will be in the next maintenance release of Juice UI. Thanks for reporting it.