# Juice UI dialog - buttons missing after postback

Tags: juice-ui

I have a JuiceUI dialog with some datepickers and a couple of buttons.  If I do a postback (unrelated to this dialog), and pop-up the dialog again, the buttons are no longer there.  See below the code I use to create the dialog.

```
<juice:Dialog ID="mDlgEditDates" TargetControlID="dlgEditDates" runat="server" AutoOpen="false" Modal="true" Buttons="{'Edit Dates': function() { EditDatesClick(); }, 'Close': function() { EditDatesClose(); } }" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the same issue as reported here: [Unable to access controls inside JuiceUI dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805359/unable-to-access-controls-inside-juiceui-dialog). Please see the answer and link to the issue on github.